# Migrating from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: html, .htaccess, http, https

I can not solve the problems with migration from http to https. My .htaccess is written as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule page/assets/img/([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ /assets/img/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule page/assets/img/uploads/([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ /assets/img/uploads/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule admin/assets/img/([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ /assets/img/$1 
[R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule admin/assets/img/uploads/([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ 
/assets/img/uploads/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

When I add to myself yet

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}=OFF
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

I get 404 pages
Tell me if you have encountered such a problem.

Comment: first check your line endings. Copy/paste from your web browser into a text editor may not work right, so after pasting into your text editor you should delete each line break and add it back in (line break = return key).
also, change to:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

Comment: Is Port 443 open in your firewall and is the server listening on it?

Comment: @JGreatorex If i do it like this: If i do it like this: *RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site(.)com/$1 [R=301,L]
https works, but the page is not accessible to me (redirect too much)

Comment: _Where_ did you place those new lines? You might also want to use the `R` flag for an explicit redirect. Manual says about the replacement, _“If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to see whether the hostname matches the current host. If it does, the scheme and hostname are stripped out and the resulting path is treated as a URL-path.”_ - not sure if that is imprecise phrasing, or if it actually checks the hostname _only_ - but if it is the latter, that could be the problem here.